# how to check if textarea field exist on form with jquery or javascript?

Tags: jquery

```
$("textarea").cleditor({ width: "800px", height: "300px" })[0].focus();
```

but when i do not have textarea felad i get

```
Error: $("textarea").cleditor({width: "800px", height: "300px"})[0] is undefined
```

how can i check if textarea field exist.

I try ($("textarea").val()) but not working correctly. I also try value() but also not working. How can i check if exist or not?

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `length` property of `jQuery` object which is non zero if it finds any element. Try this

```
if($("textarea").length > 0){
   //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var $textArea = $("textarea");
if($textArea.length > 0){
    $textArea.cleditor({ width: "800px", height: "300px" })[0].focus();
}